# Rewtite url in worpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a WordPress site, i created a new template which show some data through query string. i want to create a rewrite rule in WordPress to follow this structure.

```
www.example.com/explore/?region=berlin&sort=latest
```

to

```
www.example.com/explore/sauna-gutschein-berlin/
```

Comment: Rewrite rules usually transform the path into the query parameters.  It sounds like you have the from and to backwards in your question.

Comment: How do you know which word(s) in the URL path should be put into the `region` parameter.   How the rule know to ignore `sauna-gutshein-` and just use `berlin` for the region?

Comment: Region is query string.it change when some one submit form like if some one search for "helingson" url will be www.example.com/explore/?region=helingson&sort=latest and the it should re write like www.example.com/explore/sauna-gutschein-helingson/.Hope it makes sense

Comment: You don't need a rewrite at all.   You need your script to **redirect** to the other URL.     Presumably your script has all the information it needs to do that, no?

Comment: really i dont understand